# Clarify about local contractibility of quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider these couple of spaces: the first is $A:=\{\frac 1 n :n \in \mathbb N\}\subset\mathbb R $; the other is $B:=[0,3)\subset \mathbb C$. I must describe the topology induced by the projections $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R/A$ and $k:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C/B$. In particular, I must say if the quotient spaces are locally contractible.

In the case of  $\mathbb C/B$ we have that the open sets are all the sets corresponding to the projection of an open $D$ of $\mathbb C$, with the condition that either $D\cap B =\emptyset$ or $D\cap B =B$. Every point of $\mathbb C/B$ different from $k (3)$ and $k ([0,3))$ has an open neighbourhood trivially contractible, since the projection here is an homeomorphism. For the points $k (3)$ and $k (B)$, it suffices to take a open set $D'$ in $\mathbb C$ containing $[0,3]$; any deformation retraction of $D'$ to $B$ induces a contraction of $k (D')$ to $k (B)$, so every point has a contractible neighbourhood.

I have a problem in the other case however: consider, for every natural $n$, two disjoint intervals, one containing $\frac 1 n $ and the other containing $\frac 1 {n+1} $. Now, the countable union of all these intervals is open, and is contractible to $A$ (i.e., there is a contractible neighbourhood of $h (A) $ in the quotient space). This reasoning should be wrong (the solution says that this space isn't locally contractible) but I don't see why. Thans in advance  for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience I’ll identify $x$ and $h(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus A$ and let $a=h(A)$. It isn’t the point $a$ that’s the problem: it’s $0$. Any nbhd of $0$ in $\Bbb R\setminus A$ must contain

$$(-\epsilon,0]\cup\{a\}\cup\bigcup_{n\ge m}\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\cup\bigcup_{1\le n<m}\left(\frac1n-\epsilon,\frac1n+\epsilon\right)$$

for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $\epsilon>0$, and any $\{a\}\cup\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)$ is a copy of $S^1$.